# AJAX using rails: first item does not get updated on cart

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, depot

I have just started learning Ruby on Rails using Agile Web Develop ment by Sam Ruby. I'm currently stuck on task F: adding Ajax to cart. Everything went well till the time I added to the code for hiding an empty cart. Now when I add the first item the cart shows up empty on the side bar (it should show up with one item n the cart) but when i add the second item the cart shows up with 2 items, as it should.The code works if I add more items. I'm facing the problem only when adding the first item on the cart. I've been tearing my hair out for a day now on this problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Apologies if I haven't furnished complete details. Please let me know the additional details, if any, that would be relevant. I'm using rails 3.2.8 and ruby 1.9.3 Thanks!

_cart.html.erb

```
<div class="cart_title">Your Cart</div>
  <table>
   <%= render(cart.line_items) %>

     <tr class="total_line">
             <td colspan="2">Total</td>
             <td class="total_cell"><%= number_to_currency(cart.total_price) %></td>
     </tr>

  </table>

<%= button_to 'Empty Cart',cart, method: :delete, confirm: 'Are you sure?'%>
```

_line_item.html.erb

```
<%if @current_item==line_item%>
<tr id="current_item">
<% else %>
<tr>
<% end %>

  <td><%= line_item.quantity %> &times;</td>
  <td><%= line_item.product.title %></td>
  <td class="item_price" ><%= number_to_currency(line_item.total_price) %></td>
  <td><%= button_to 'Remove Item', line_item, method: :delete, confirm: 'Are you   sure?'%>
</tr>
```

create.js.erb

```
 $("#notice").hide();

 if ($('#cart tr').length > 0) { $('#cart').show('blind', 1000); }

 $('#cart').html("<%=j render @cart %>");

 $('#current_item').css({'background-color':'#88cc88'}).
   animate({'background-color':'#114411'}, 1000);
```

application.js.erb

```
<html>
  <head>
   <title>Pragprog Books Online Store</title>
    <!-- START:stylesheet -->
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "scaffold" %>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "depot", :media => "all" %><!-- <label id="code.slt"/> -->
   <!-- END:stylesheet -->
   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
   <%= csrf_meta_tag %><!-- <label id="code.csrf"/> -->
  </head>
  <body id="store">
   <div id="banner">
    <%= image_tag("logo.png") %>
    <%= @page_title || "Pragmatic Bookshelf" %><!-- <label id="code.depot.e.title"/> -->
   </div>
   <div id="columns">
    <div id="side">
       <a href="/">Home</a><br />
       <a href="/faq">Questions</a><br />
       <a href="/news">News</a><br />
       <a href="/contact">Contact</a><br />
       <%if @cart%>
       <%= hidden_div_if(@cart.line_items.empty?, id:"cart") do%>
               <%=render @cart%>
         <% end %>
       <% end %>

    </div>
    <div id="main">
     <%= yield %><!-- <label id="code.depot.e.include"/> -->
    </div>
   </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

~

Comment: managed to solve it myself :)..while typing out the problem i got a hint that the problem was somehow with the rendering itself and so it was .. the solution is to set the show parameter to 0 in { $('#cart').show('blind', 1000); }  the code should now be { $('#cart').show('blind', 0); }

Comment: If you solved it then post it into an answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

managed to solve it myself :)..while typing out the problem i got a hint that the problem was somehow with the rendering itself and so it was .. the solution is to set the show parameter to 0 in { $('#cart').show('blind', 1000); } the code should now be { $('#cart').show('blind', 0); }

@Btuman done!!